# Select records from 4 different tables using if statements

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT sup.qid,sup.title ,SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 1, 1) as t ,
 CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 1, 1) = "s" 
 THEN  select name from staff st where st.id= SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 2, 1) 
 ELSE 
     when SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 1, 1) = "p" 
           THEN  select name from users p where p.id= SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 2, 1)  
   END AS user name 
 FROM `support_queries` sup
```

Here userid will contain the uid along with a prefix, for staff the prefix is **s**.

And for users it is **p**, I want to fetch the user details  who posted the query.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and expected result from your sample data.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh syntax looks more like mysql, lets remove the other

Comment: a case expression can not be used as flow control. it can only return a single value. Further more, a sub query can only return a single value (unless used for in, exists, or as a derived table).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT sup.qid,
       sup.title,
       SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 1, 1) AS t,
       CASE SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 1, 1)
         WHEN 's' THEN staff.name
         WHEN 'p' THEN users.name
         ELSE NULL
       END AS user_name
FROM   support_queries sub
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
             ON SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 2, LENGTH(sup.userid) - 1) = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN staff
             ON SUBSTRING(sup.userid, 2, LENGTH(sup.userid) - 1) = staff.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to put this logic into the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT sq.qid, sq.title, LEFT(sup.userid, 1) AS t,
       COALESCE(s.name, u.name) as user_name
FROM support_queries sq LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON SUBSTRING(sq.userid, 2) = u.id AND
        LEFT(sq.userid, 1) = 'p' LEFT JOIN
     staff s
     ON SUBSTRING(sq.userid, 2) = s.id AND
        LEFT(sq.userid, 1) = 's';
```

Or more simply as:

```
SELECT sq.qid, sq.title, LEFT(sup.userid, 1) AS t,
       COALESCE(s.name, u.name) as user_name
FROM support_queries sq LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON sq.userid = CONCAT('p', u.id) LEFT JOIN
     staff s
     ON sq.userid = CONCAT('s', s.id);
```